# Restrict Indexing to Google Custom Search Only

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, google-index

We are looking at using Google CSE to power the search functionality for our Extranet which is restricted to staff access only. How can we restrict indexing so Google indexes the site for the embedded CSE but that indexed content won't be accessible on the public Google search engine?

Comment: I don't think you can without a Google Search Appliance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is interested I spoke to Google about it and they said its not possible. Apparently Google CSE uses the same index as the Google main search engine, all the suggested was using the Google Search Appliance.